How to bridge null rows with incremented value?
I am working in Databricks, and I have a dataframe (let's call it 'df') with several null rows within a column:
+----+------------+-------+
| id | date       | value |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 2024-01-01 | 0     |
| 1  | 2024-01-02 | null  |
| 1  | 2024-01-03 | null  |
| 1  | 2024-01-04 | null  |
| 1  | 2024-01-05 | 4     |
| 1  | 2024-01-06 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-20 | 0     |
| 2  | 2024-03-21 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-22 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-23 | 3     |
| 2  | 2024-03-24 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-25 | 0     |
| 2  | 2024-03-26 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-27 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-28 | null  |
| 2  | 2024-03-29 | 4     |
+----+------------+-------+

I need to partition by 'id' and order by 'date' to replace these nulls with the value of the previous row incremented by one, but I'm at a loss.
Pseudocode algorithm:
for (int i = 1; i < number_of_rows; i++)
{
  if value[i] == null
  {
    value[i] = value[i-1] + 1
  }
}

(it'd be okay to skip the first row and just accept the value as-is, null or not)
The output should therefore be the following:
+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| id | date       | value | value_filled |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 2024-01-01 | 0     | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-02 | null  | 1            |
| 1  | 2024-01-03 | null  | 2            |
| 1  | 2024-01-04 | null  | 3            |
| 1  | 2024-01-05 | 4     | 4            |
| 1  | 2024-01-06 | null  | 5            |
| 2  | 2024-03-20 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-21 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-22 | null  | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-23 | 3     | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-24 | null  | 4            |
| 2  | 2024-03-25 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-26 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-27 | null  | 2            |
| 2  | 2024-03-28 | null  | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-29 | 4     | 4            |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+

I have already figured out how to replace the nulls with the previous value using the last function, e.g.:
w = Window.partitionBy('vin').orderBy('scan_date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
df = df.withColumn('value_filled', F.last('value', ignorenulls=True).over(w))

+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| id | date       | value | value_filled |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 2024-01-01 | 0     | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-02 | null  | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-03 | null  | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-04 | null  | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-05 | 4     | 4            |
| 1  | 2024-01-06 | null  | 4            |
| 2  | 2024-03-20 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-21 | null  | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-22 | null  | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-23 | 3     | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-24 | null  | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-25 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-26 | null  | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-27 | null  | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-28 | null  | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-29 | 4     | 4            |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+

I've tried various approaches to add one to the previous column if the current column is null, but at most I can only get the first null in the group of nulls to update, such as:
w = Window.partitionBy('vin').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
df = df.withColumn('value', F.when(F.isnull(F.col('value')), F.last(F.col('value'), \
  ignorenulls=True).over(w) + 1).otherwise(F.col('value')))

+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| id | date       | value | value_filled |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 2024-01-01 | 0     | 0            |
| 1  | 2024-01-02 | null  | 1            |
| 1  | 2024-01-03 | null  | 1            |
| 1  | 2024-01-04 | null  | 1            |
| 1  | 2024-01-05 | 4     | 4            |
| 1  | 2024-01-06 | null  | 5            |
| 2  | 2024-03-20 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-21 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-22 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-23 | 3     | 3            |
| 2  | 2024-03-24 | null  | 4            |
| 2  | 2024-03-25 | 0     | 0            |
| 2  | 2024-03-26 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-27 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-28 | null  | 1            |
| 2  | 2024-03-29 | 4     | 4            |
+----+------------+-------+--------------+


The trick to solve such kind of problems is first create the appropriate window.
If you can recognize the appropriate window through your data, then incrementing values are easy.
In order to recognize the window, first we identify the start of the window.
To do that we create a lead column of the value column. To denote the start of the window is then as simple as the first row which has non-null value and a null lead value. We will denote such start values by value 1 and non-start values as 0.
Then to create unique groups, we will just sum this value. This will give us a unique groupid over which we want to replace values.
Then it is a matter of extract last_non_value column over this group and create a "ranked - 1" column and just adding these two columns.
Following is the code which achieves.
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum, when, lag, lead
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("InterpolateNulls").getOrCreate()


data = [
    (1, '2024-01-01', 0),
    (1, '2024-01-02', None),
    (1, '2024-01-03', None),
    (1, '2024-01-04', None),
    (1, '2024-01-05', 4),
    (1, '2024-01-06', None),
    (2, '2024-03-20', 0),
    (2, '2024-03-21', None),
    (2, '2024-03-22', None),
    (2, '2024-03-23', 3),
    (2, '2024-03-24', None),
    (2, '2024-03-25', 0),
    (2, '2024-03-26', None),
    (2, '2024-03-27', None),
    (2, '2024-03-28', None),
    (2, '2024-03-29', 4)
]
columns = ['id', 'date', 'value']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)
df = df.withColumn("was_missing", when(col("value").isNull(), 1).otherwise(0))
df.show()


windowSpecLast = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
windowSpecNormal = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

df = df.withColumn("last_nonnull_value", last("value", ignorenulls=True).over(windowSpecLast))

df = df.withColumn("lead_value", lead("value").over(windowSpecNormal))





df = df.withColumn("start_col", F.when(
    ((F.col("value").isNotNull()) & (F.col("lead_value").isNull())), 1).otherwise(0))


windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df_grouped = df.withColumn("groupId", F.sum("start_col").over(windowSpec))

windowSpecGrouped = Window.partitionBy("id", "groupid").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)


df_ranked = df_grouped.withColumn("ranked", rank().over(windowSpecGrouped) - 1)

df_ranked.show()

df_final = df_ranked.withColumn("value_filled",  col("last_nonnull_value") + col("ranked"))


df_final.select("id", "date", "value", "value_filled").show()

Output :
+---+----------+-----+-----------+
| id|      date|value|was_missing|
+---+----------+-----+-----------+
|  1|2024-01-01|    0|          0|
|  1|2024-01-02| NULL|          1|
|  1|2024-01-03| NULL|          1|
|  1|2024-01-04| NULL|          1|
|  1|2024-01-05|    4|          0|
|  1|2024-01-06| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-20|    0|          0|
|  2|2024-03-21| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-22| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-23|    3|          0|
|  2|2024-03-24| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-25|    0|          0|
|  2|2024-03-26| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-27| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-28| NULL|          1|
|  2|2024-03-29|    4|          0|
+---+----------+-----+-----------+

+---+----------+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+
| id|      date|value|was_missing|last_nonnull_value|lead_value|start_col|groupId|ranked|
+---+----------+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+
|  1|2024-01-01|    0|          0|                 0|      NULL|        1|      1|     0|
|  1|2024-01-02| NULL|          1|                 0|      NULL|        0|      1|     1|
|  1|2024-01-03| NULL|          1|                 0|      NULL|        0|      1|     2|
|  1|2024-01-04| NULL|          1|                 0|         4|        0|      1|     3|
|  1|2024-01-05|    4|          0|                 4|      NULL|        1|      2|     0|
|  1|2024-01-06| NULL|          1|                 4|      NULL|        0|      2|     1|
|  2|2024-03-20|    0|          0|                 0|      NULL|        1|      1|     0|
|  2|2024-03-21| NULL|          1|                 0|      NULL|        0|      1|     1|
|  2|2024-03-22| NULL|          1|                 0|         3|        0|      1|     2|
|  2|2024-03-23|    3|          0|                 3|      NULL|        1|      2|     0|
|  2|2024-03-24| NULL|          1|                 3|         0|        0|      2|     1|
|  2|2024-03-25|    0|          0|                 0|      NULL|        1|      3|     0|
|  2|2024-03-26| NULL|          1|                 0|      NULL|        0|      3|     1|
|  2|2024-03-27| NULL|          1|                 0|      NULL|        0|      3|     2|
|  2|2024-03-28| NULL|          1|                 0|         4|        0|      3|     3|
|  2|2024-03-29|    4|          0|                 4|      NULL|        1|      4|     0|
+---+----------+-----+-----------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+

+---+----------+-----+------------+
| id|      date|value|value_filled|
+---+----------+-----+------------+
|  1|2024-01-01|    0|           0|
|  1|2024-01-02| NULL|           1|
|  1|2024-01-03| NULL|           2|
|  1|2024-01-04| NULL|           3|
|  1|2024-01-05|    4|           4|
|  1|2024-01-06| NULL|           5|
|  2|2024-03-20|    0|           0|
|  2|2024-03-21| NULL|           1|
|  2|2024-03-22| NULL|           2|
|  2|2024-03-23|    3|           3|
|  2|2024-03-24| NULL|           4|
|  2|2024-03-25|    0|           0|
|  2|2024-03-26| NULL|           1|
|  2|2024-03-27| NULL|           2|
|  2|2024-03-28| NULL|           3|
|  2|2024-03-29|    4|           4|
+---+----------+-----+------------+


Awesome, thank you!! I had some of the pieces of your approach in my previous attempts, and I was thinking that trying to create unique group ids for each set of monotonically increasing values, and ranking the group would be a good approach, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do that. Your approach works perfectly!

You can first create a temporary group column that makes the group for 1 value and successive nulls. Then by grouping with id and the temporary group column, create another temporary column where it has 0 on the row with non-null value and increment by 1 for successive null rows. Finally, you can add the first value for the group and the increment value for the row to get the result.
grp_window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')
inc_window = Window.partitionBy('id', 'grp').orderBy('date')

df = (df.withColumn('grp', F.sum(F.col('value').isNotNull().cast('int')).over(grp_window))
      .withColumn('inc', F.row_number().over(inc_window) - 1)
      .withColumn('value_filled', F.first('value', ignorenulls=True).over(inc_window) + F.col('inc')))

+---+----------+-----+---+---+------------+
| id|      date|value|grp|inc|value_filled|
+---+----------+-----+---+---+------------+
|  1|2024-01-01|    0|  1|  0|           0|
|  1|2024-01-02| null|  1|  1|           1|
|  1|2024-01-03| null|  1|  2|           2|
|  1|2024-01-04| null|  1|  3|           3|
|  1|2024-01-05|    4|  2|  0|           4|
|  1|2024-01-06| null|  2|  1|           5|
|  2|2024-03-20|    0|  1|  0|           0|
|  2|2024-03-21| null|  1|  1|           1|
|  2|2024-03-22| null|  1|  2|           2|
|  2|2024-03-23|    3|  2|  0|           3|
|  2|2024-03-24| null|  2|  1|           4|
|  2|2024-03-25|    0|  3|  0|           0|
|  2|2024-03-26| null|  3|  1|           1|
|  2|2024-03-27| null|  3|  2|           2|
|  2|2024-03-28| null|  3|  3|           3|
|  2|2024-03-29|    4|  4|  0|           4|
+---+----------+-----+---+---+------------+


This is a neat solution.
