How to create my own custom imputter to input constant values seamlessly in pyspark.ml pipelines
I would like to optimize the imputation of missing values on my dataset through a CV search. This is trivial to do in sklearn, with which I am familiar -- however, I am for the first time working with cluster distributed spark dataframes, and must use the pyspark.ml module.
As far as I can tell, the pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer class is unable to impute (chosen) constant values, which is one thing I want to test.
How would you suggest I do this? I looked a little into writting a custom transformer, which is also easy within the sklearn API, but I have not found a clear way to do this in pyspark.ml.

can you give an example where you are stuck? this answer could provide some ideas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421705/how-to-bridge-null-rows-with-incremented-value/78424288#78424288

@user238607 thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for, I want something whose hyperparameters can be tuned through a CrossValidator.
